# Button Zoom on hover effect creates text deformation

Tags: html, css, button

Like in the topic I created a button with zoom on hover effect, however the text is changing on hover, the font is deformed I dont know actually how to describe it. Is there a solution for this?

Here's example :

```css
.superBtn {
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #008cfd, #1092fd, #1e98fd, #2b9dfd, #37a3fc);
    background-color: initial;
    border-color: initial;
    
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.zoomnav2{
    transition: transform .2s;
}

.zoomnav2:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1); 
}
```

```html
<button class="superBtn zoomnav2">CONTACT ME!</button>
```

Comment: Please define "deformed" for me it is just larger...

Comment: Please explain your question so that we are able to know what you are trying to do

Comment: when u stop hovering the text deforms, look at ```E``` for example, the spaces betwen lines are smaller

Comment: and when you hover over the button the text is shrinking or something

Comment: @Simonsoft177 i'm sorry but i don't see any mistakes. I zoomed in 400% in my browser, but I still couldn't see any errors